# Meaning of "there are many and several"

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does the phrase "there are many and several" mean?

> ...which represent the highest quality properties in the market of which **there are many and several**.

Comment: It is the [second meaning of several (adjective)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/several?q=several)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Several](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/several_2)* here is used as an adjective to mean *separate or different*. Here it refers to the fact that there are not only many properties but different kinds of properties.